Mustard type paste in my radiator
There is a mustard type paste constantly in my radiator when I remove the cap, I have a 2017, Ram 1500 laramie, 5.7L with oil cooler. I have flushed the system several times and
re-introduced pre-diluted antifreeze 50/50 mix made for my vehicle.
Why might this still be occurring? What else can I look for? thank you, I will appreciate and feedback I can get.

Mustard! French style, spicy brown or Dijon?
Just kidding, but I assume it's brownish and I think it's an emulsion of oil and water and glycol. This would mean that motor oil is somehow getting into your coolant. Maybe from the oil cooler, maybe a crack or porosity in the block, maybe the head gasket.
Do you want confirmation that it's oil?
Get a sheet of paper towel. Take a small sample of the mustard-y stuff and smear it on the paper towel. Take a separate sample about the same size of clean 50-50 coolant and smear it on the paper towel right next to the mustard-y smear. Wait 24 hours.
Now hold the paper towel with a bright light behind it. The 50-50 coolant streak may or may not be visible as a translucent bright spot on the paper towel, depending on the temperature and humidity where it has spent the last 24 hours.
If the mustard-y streak looks the same as the 50-50 streak, it's not oil. But if it looks translucent, brighter by far than the coolant streak when there's a strong light behind it, it's oil.
Other answers or comments may add possible sources of oil in the coolant.

Head gasket is normally the answer here. Or at least you hope it's the answer, because whilst a head gasket replacement is not cheap, it's still less painful than a new engine (cracked block). Oil cooler might not be too bad, but most smaller cars don't have one.

@Graham - A 5.7L Ram isn't a small vehicle. The oil cooler is the first place I'd look in this case.

@Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Fair point.

Emulsion of oil and water, so it's more like mayonnaise than mustard?

@pipe: I'm gonna suggest migrating this question to cooking.se (j/k!)
